# Using Apache RewriteRule

Tags: apache-http-server, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I'm attempting to get a very simple RewriteRule working in Apache - I've set Apache2 up (in Vagrant) and run `sudo a2enmod rewrite` successfully (and restarted Apache after), with the following trivial `httpd.conf`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /abc.html /def.html
```

where `abc.html` and `def.html` are two one-line HTML files in `/var/www`, the default web directory that Apache sets up. Even so, the rule doesn't seem to work - I get the contents of `abc.html` when I navigate to `http://localhost:8080/abc.html`. A corresponding `Redirect` rule works, but I need to add more logic than a redirect will allow once I get this simple example working.

Answer (score 0):

Though the rule should work when put into a [server config context](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), it only worked when put inside a `VirtualHost` definition, if that `VirtualHost` isn't already defined in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default`.